# What does "Drop an E" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is a scene about a psychiatrist giving advise to his patient. and this psychiatrist is like a lunatic. he is always like to go out with his friends and party. and the patient is like a humble one. so he is giving advise to his patient. below you can see the dialog between psychiatrist and the patient.

> Patient : What do you do when you get depressed?
>
> Psychiatrist : I get twatted with Ratty and Nonce.
>
> Psychiatrist : And I hate all this namby-pamby nonsense, you know?
>
> Psychiatrist : This bleeding heart...
>
> Psychiatrist : "toxic masculinity,
>
> Psychiatrist : It's okay to cry!"
>
> Psychiatrist : It's also OK to have five pints, drop an E,
>
> Psychiatrist : And do some fucking trollop from behind against the
> bins.

So what does he mean by **''drop an E''**?

Comment: The mention of "ratty and nonse" make me think this is a quote from After Life.  But **you haven't told us the source**,

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry, but i thought that is relevant. next time i will mention the source.

Comment: Your title and the question need correcting. It's 'drop **an** E'.

Comment: ok, i will fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means 'swallow a tablet of the illegal drug "ecstasy".'

"Drop" is one of the many slang words meaning "swallow drugs" it is particularly used in the phrase "drop acid" (in the sense of "drop in the mouth".  And "E" is one of slang names of the drug MDMA, as an abbreviation of the street name for MDMA: "Ecstasy".